# Problem animating speaker making fluid move

Tags: animation, objects, fluid-simulation

I am new here, I did a few projects but now I
got stuck with a new one, what I am trying to do is to make a speaker reacting to the music, but the problem is when I try to simulate some water which is affected by the speaker moves, I tried that but nothing happened, then, I realized that there has to be an animation in the timeline to interact with the water and I can't find how to make the speaker react to the music and make an animation of it. I don't know if this makes sense. Here is one example of what I am trying to do: https://vimeo.com/191210306 , if it's not possible I just try to animate it manually. Thank you!

Comment: In the timeline animation tab, near the play/pause button. There is a little record button. Auto keying. If you turn that on and let the timeline play while the simulation is running, I guess it will record the keyframes. But it depends on what kind of movement the speaker makes. If it's limited to location and scale transformations, it should be easy. If it actually changes the fundamental shape of the mesh, its gonna be more difficult, cause I don't think shape keys can be auto keyed.

Comment: This video outlines the pricess of making things in blender move to music. In the video, he uses a displace modifier, but I achieved a "moving speaker head" by assigning a vertex group to a circle on top of a box and then used a wave modifier to move that group. I set keys on both the speed and the height on the wave modifier, however you might want to reduce their strength a little. Video is here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8RHRNZQEuE. Afterwards, if you want splattering paint, place a fluid simulation on top of the moving "speaker head".

Comment: @ChristopherBennett omg, after a few hours I managed to make it work as you said, the only thing that I suggest if anyone is reading this, on the modifier tab on the moving object put the wave first then the fluid simulation(you also have to set the object that you want to be moving to an effector type fluid. Thank you!

Comment: @VladRaboj I'm happy that you found a way to make it work, using the suggested video but also improving the process. You could do a great thing: create an answer yourself (even approve it later) to help other users here to understand howto, since that video could be later unavailable ...